# What kind of contractor would I need to service or replace pull down attic stairs?

Tags: attic, stairs, contractors

I have attic loft with pull down stairs access to it and I need it either serviced or replaced with a new rope system. Can you advice what kind of contractor I'd need for this?

As you can see on the picture below it is not your basic attic ladder but quote sophisticated garage like pull down stairs.

The trouble with it, it's too loud pulling down and especially pushing back up. I'm thinking to move my office up to the loft but it'd be not possible to move those stairs at 1am when everyone is sleeping...

[image: Pull down attic stairs]

Comment: Tried giving all the moving parts a good lube?

Comment: If you can see a manufacturer's name, they may have suggestions, or at least parts/manuals that could help whomever works on this. Bessler is one company that makes single-stringer (non-folding) attic stairs: http://www.bessler.com/Bfaq.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to be exactly like a garage door. I take it lowering the stairs tensions a spring attached to the drums so it is easier to raise. Exact same system as sectional garage doors. The springs can be very dangerous to someone unaware of their potential. I think you should look for someone experienced with sectional garage doors, they will understand this system immediately.

If the rollers are hard plastic or rubber, the system could be made quieter by going to softer rubber. Applying foam to the closure panel could reduce any drumming effect, but will take careful detailing to keep it out of the way and looking attractive. Rubber padding could be added to stops to limit banging. A certain amount of noise is the nature of the beast, unfortunately.